# How can I get ms-access to save label settings?

Tags: ms-access, printing

I am running a database on Access 2007. I have set up a report to print out as a label via a label printer (Dymo 750). This works fine on my machine but when my colleague, who runs the database via Runtime, tries to print the same label, it reverts to an erroneous label size. The size can be corrected in the Runtime version using print preview/settings but the correct settings are never retained. I have never had any problem on my own machine which runs the full version of Access. The version of the Dymo software is exactly the same on both machines.

Thank you for any help on this problem.

Comment: His settings in Windows for the Dymo printer is probably different from yours.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your reply. Do you know where I should start looking at the windows settings?

Comment: That's the properties of the printer including their paper formats.

Answer (score 1):

Access 2007 has a bug where reports tend to lose their specialized print settings. If you have the option, upgrade to a newer version.

If that is not an option try this:

- Go to design mode on your report.
- In design mode go to the page settings (do not preview) and set up your printer settings.
- Save and close the report WITHOUT printing or previewing or doing anything else.

From that point on as long as you never go back to the page settings and the report is never opened on a computer that does not have the exact same printer object (printer name and driver/model) it should stick.

However if you ever go to the print settings during a print preview or try to print to a different printer, the report will lose its print settings.

Comment: Hi SunKnight0, thanks for your answer. My colleague is working in on the Runtime version of access so there is no design mode for him. Therefore I cannot carry out your solution. I have never had a problem with my (full Access) version.